# Flash Issue - gotoAndPlay/gotoAndStop

Tags: flash

Don't get me wrong, I know Flash and normally I dont have problems when the programming isnt too high. Now this seems like an easy question, but I've been scratching my head for the last couple hours trying to figure out what is wrong.

I'm doing this animation, and at the end, I simply want the user to click on the button for a replay for example. Yesterday all was working perfect, although now, I must've added something that makes it unable to work correctly.

So basically I have my frame with a stop(); and then the following code (in the button element):

```
    on (release)
    {
         _root.gotoAndStop("menu");
    }
```

I mean what's an easier thing to do in Flash right?

Well right now it goes on the frame "menu" for a quarter of a second and then comes right back to the actual frame with the button.

(Flash AS2 btw, if it wasn't already obvious)

Anyways, let me know if you already experienced this issue, because right now I just can't seem to find whats happening.

Thanks a bunch to anyone!

Comment: Using the code you're using in the way you explain should work without any problems. We could sit and guess what your mistake is, but it would be shots in the dark. Your issue is elsewhere and as of now you are the best person to answer this question without providing us the Fla as citizen conn said.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanted to replay, instead of going back to the beginning, you should have it do _root.gotoAndPlay("menu").

If that doesn't work then we'd need to see your fla.